# Gulp3 node 10.16.3 globalThis

Tags: gulp

I tried to upgraded to gulp4 but now I need to go back to gulp3. I installed the node I had installed version 10.16.3 but now I am getting this error message? it was working in the past for me using this version so I am not sure what happen.

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.6
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 ia32
```

> C:\WebProjects\ITF.Web>gulp prod
> ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
> at Object. (C:\WebProjects\ITF.Web\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\utils\general.js:12:1)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
> at Object. (C:\WebProjects\ITF.Web\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\application.js:24:19)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)

Gulp file

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
    var runSequence = require("run-sequence");
    var tslint = require("gulp-tslint");
    var typedoc = require("gulp-typedoc");
    var superstatic = require("superstatic");
    var shell = require("gulp-shell");
    var typescript = require("gulp-typescript");
    var tsProject = typescript.createProject("tsconfig.json");
    var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
    var rimraf = require("gulp-rimraf");
    var replace = require("gulp-replace");
    var rename = require("gulp-rename");
    var ignore = require("gulp-ignore");
    var insert = require("gulp-insert");
    var concat = require("gulp-concat");
    var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
    var tslintStylish = require("gulp-tslint-stylish");
    var util = require("gulp-util");
    var commentSwap = require("gulp-comment-swap");
    var tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
    var gulp_jspm = require("gulp-jspm");
    var inlineNg2Template = require("gulp-inline-ng2-template");
    
    /**
     * Typescript configuration 
     **/
    var paths = {
        dist: "./dist",    
        sources: "./App/**/*.ts"    
    };
    
    gulp.task("prod", function (callback) {
        runSequence(
            "compile",
            "bundle",
            "min",
            function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("Production build finished successfully");
                }
                callback(error);
            });
    });
    
    /**
     * Compile TypeScript sources
     */
    gulp.task("compile", ["clean"], function () {
        return gulp.src("./App/**/*.ts")
            .pipe(inlineNg2Template({
                base: "/",                  // Angular2 application base folder
                target: "es6",              // Can swap to es5
                indent: 2,                  // Indentation (spaces)
                useRelativePaths: false,     // Use components relative assset paths
                removeLineBreaks: false,     // Content will be included as one line
                templateExtension: ".html", // Update according to your file extension
                templateFunction: false    // If using a function instead of a string for `templateUrl`, pass a reference to that function here
            }))
            .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
            .pipe(ignore("References.js"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/App"));
    });
    
    /**
     * Bundle application parts
     */
    gulp.task("bundle:template", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/TemplateEdit.js", "template");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:agents", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Maintenance/Agents.js", "agents");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:indications", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Maintenance/Indications.js", "indications");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:styleguidenotes", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Components/NoteEditor/NoteEditor.js", "styleguidenotes");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:dynamicdictionary", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Maintenance/DynamicDictionary.js", "dynamicdictionary");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:splitdynamicdictionary", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Maintenance/SplitDynamicDictionary.js", "splitdynamicdictionary");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:styleguidenotesdevprocess", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/StyleGuideNote/Index.js", "styleguidenotesdevprocess");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:scheduling", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Scheduling/Index.js", "scheduling");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:templatesmanagement", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/TemplatesManagement/Index.js", "templatesmanagement");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:review", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Review/Index.js", "review");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:ownedreview", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/OwnedReview/Index.js", "ownedreview");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:pdfqueue", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/PdfQueue/Index.js", "pdfqueue");
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle:admin", function () {
        return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Admin/Index.js", "admin");
    });
    
    
    gulp.task("bundle", function (callback) {
        runSequence(
            "bundle:template",
            "bundle:agents",
            "bundle:indications",
            "bundle:styleguidenotes",        
            "bundle:dynamicdictionary",
            "bundle:splitdynamicdictionary",
            "bundle:styleguidenotesdevprocess",
            "bundle:scheduling",
            "bundle:templatesmanagement",
            "bundle:review",
            "bundle:ownedreview",
            "bundle:pdfqueue",
            "bundle:admin",
            function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("Bundling finished successfully");
                }
                callback(error);
            });
    });
    
    /**
     * Create application package
     */
    gulp.task("min:template", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("template", true);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:agents", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("agents", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:indications", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("indications", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:styleguidenotes", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("styleguidenotes", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:dynamicdictionary", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("dynamicdictionary", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:splitdynamicdictionary", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("splitdynamicdictionary", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:styleguidenotesdevprocess", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("styleguidenotesdevprocess", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:scheduling", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("scheduling", false);
    });
    
    
    gulp.task("min:templatesmanagement", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("templatesmanagement", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:review", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("review", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:ownedreview", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("ownedreview", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min:pdfqueue", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("pdfqueue", false);
    });
    gulp.task("min:admin", function () {
        return createProductionPackageTask("admin", false);
    });
    
    gulp.task("min", function (callback) {
        runSequence(
            "min:template",
            "min:agents",
            "min:indications",
            "min:styleguidenotes",        
            "min:dynamicdictionary",
            "min:splitdynamicdictionary",
            "min:styleguidenotesdevprocess",
            "min:scheduling",
            "min:templatesmanagement",
            "min:review",
            "min:ownedreview",
            "min:pdfqueue",
            "min:admin",
            function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("Minification finished successfully");
                }
                callback(error);
            });
    });
    
    /**
     * Clean build folder
     */
    gulp.task("clean", function () {
        return gulp.src(paths.dist, { read: false }).pipe(rimraf({ force: true }));
    });
    
    /**
     * Helper methods
     */
    var createBundleTask = function (entryPoint, packageId) {
        if (typeof entryPoint === "undefined") {
            throw "ArgumentNullException: entryPoint";
        }
    
        if (typeof packageId === "undefined") {
            throw "ArgumentNullException: packageId";
        }
    
        var task = gulp.src(entryPoint)
            .pipe(gulp_jspm({ selfExecutingBundle: true }))
            .pipe(rename(packageId + ".bundle.js"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/bundle"));
    
        return task;
    };
    
    var createProductionPackageTask = function (packageId, uglifyDestination) {
        if (typeof packageId === "undefined") {
            throw "ArgumentNullException: packageId";
        }
    
        var filesArry = [
            "./node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
            "./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
            "./node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js",
            paths.dist + "/bundle/" + packageId + ".bundle.js"
        ];
    
        var task = gulp.src(filesArry)
            .pipe(concat(packageId + "_concatApp.js"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/temp"))
            .pipe(rename(packageId + ".bundle.min.js"));
    
        if (uglifyDestination) {
            task = task.pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }));
        }
    
        return task.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/build"));    
    };
```

Error installing typedoc@^2.2

```
PM> npm install -D 'typedoc@^2.2'
npm : npm ERR! code ETARGET
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install -D 'typedoc@^2.2'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm ERR! code ETARGET:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for typedoc@2.2.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-18T12_02_53_816Z-debug-0.log
```

Debug log

```
   128 verbose lifecycle nccn-cott@1.0.0~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
129 verbose lifecycle nccn-cott@1.0.0~postinstall: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\WebProjects\COTT\COTT\OrderTemplateTool.Web\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\;C:\Users\mcdevitt\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\mcdevitt\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\mcdevitt\AppData\Roaming\npm
130 verbose lifecycle nccn-cott@1.0.0~postinstall: CWD: C:\WebProjects\COTT\COTT\OrderTemplateTool.Web
131 silly lifecycle nccn-cott@1.0.0~postinstall: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'typings install' ]
132 timing audit submit Completed in 171ms
133 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 172ms
134 timing audit body Completed in 2ms
135 silly lifecycle nccn-cott@1.0.0~postinstall: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
136 info lifecycle nccn-cott@1.0.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
137 verbose stack Error: nccn-cott@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
137 verbose stack Exit status 1
137 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
137 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
137 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
137 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
137 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
137 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
138 verbose pkgid nccn-cott@1.0.0
```

Comment: Are you using gulp-typedoc?

Comment: In the gulp file?

Comment: Can you show your gulpfile?

Comment: Updates with gulpfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Node.js 10 was dropped in TypeDoc 0.21 ([see announcement](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0210-2021-06-18)). To keep using Node.js 10, pin gulp-typedoc to version 2.2:

```
npm install -D 'gulp-typedoc@^2.2'
```

gulp-typedoc 2.2.9 is the last version of gulp-typedoc that depends on a legacy version of TypeDoc, while gulp-typedoc 3.0 doesn't have a version requirement.

Comment: I updated with the error I am getting now

Comment: @Jefferson My bad! Should be `npm install -D 'gulp-typedoc@^2.2'`. I've fixed that.

Comment: I am getting this error now `C:\WebProjects\ITD\Web>gulp prod
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined`

Comment: @Jefferson Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: any idea what this Error: Refusing to delete means?

Comment: @Jefferson Have you tried to delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again?

Comment: if I do that I get this `'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Do I then need to reinstall gulp?

Comment: @Jefferson `gulp` should be installed as a devDependency: you could run `npm install -D gulp`

Comment: yes but I am still getting that error

Comment: is that Debug log stopping it from installing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244000/discussion-between-goto-0-and-jefferson).